# $X,Y$ has same distribution function $\implies P(X=Y)=1$ ?

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose $X,Y$ are two random variables with same distribution function. Denote $F_X$ for the distribution function of $X$ and $F_Y$ the distribution function of $Y$, then $F_X(t)=F_Y(t)$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$. I want to know if $P(X=Y)=1$. If this is not the case, could you show me some counter example.

PS: if the statement is valid, I'm looking for some argument not using expectations.

Thank you.

Comment: You flip two coins. Will they land the same side almost surely?

Comment: No, generally not, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $P(X=Y) = 0$, if the distribution function is continuous.

Comment: The flip coin idea is so simple...I was mislead thinking about continuity with density functions and trying to find some measure theoretic argument to show it's true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't hold at all if $X$ and $Y$ are non-degenerate. Consider for example the space $\Omega = \{0, 1\}$ with the uniform distribution and the random variables $X(\omega) = \omega$ and $Y(\omega) = 1 - \omega$. They both have the distribution, but $P(X = Y) = 0$.

The reason for this is that the connection between the distribution of a random variable and the probability measure on the domain of $X$ and $Y$ is very weak. For example, two random variables can be defined on completely different probability spaces, but still have the same distribution.

Comment: I know the theory but my experience is weak, I need to do more exercises get a better understanding. Thank you for pointing out the weak connection between the distribution function and the probability measure.

Answer (score 2):

The statement is *not* valid.

Flip a fair coin.

If $X$ denotes the number of heads and $Y$ the number of tails then they have the same distribution, but $X\neq Y$ hence $P(X=Y)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be normally distributed and $Y\equiv -X$. Clearly, $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution, because the normal distribution function is symmetric about $0$: 
\begin{align*}
F_Y(t)=&\,\mathbb P(Y\leq t)=\mathbb P(-X\leq t)=\mathbb P(X\geq -t)=1-\mathbb P(X<-t)=1-\mathbb P(X\leq -t)\\=&\,1-F_X(-t)=F_X(t).
\end{align*}
However, $$\mathbb P(X=Y)=\mathbb P(2X=0)=\mathbb P(X=0)=0.$$